# Make JLabel and JText smaller on my JPanel screen

Tags: java, swing

So I'm creating a game. So far I have created the JPanels side by side. On the right side is where the users enters his name. But the text box are way too big and I want to make them smaller where it can be placed on the Right side panel in the centre at the top. But not sure how to go about doing this.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
/**
 * Write a description of class Reversi here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Reversi
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel userName1; 
    private JLabel userName2;
    private JTextField textUsername1;
    private JTextField textUsername2;
    /**
     * 
     */
    public Reversi()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        gui();
        
    }

    /**
     * 
     * 
     */
    public void gui()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Reversi Game");
        frame.setSize(800,800);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        
        JPanel container = new JPanel();
        container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
       
        
        
        JPanel userInterface = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        userInterface.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        userInterface.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(0));;
        userInterface.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,700));
        
        JPanel board = new JPanel();
        board.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        board.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1));
        board.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 700));
        
        
        userName1 = new JLabel("Enter First user: ");
        userName2 = new JLabel("Enter second user: ");
        textUsername1 = new JTextField(20);
        textUsername2 = new JTextField(20);
        userInterface.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
        userInterface.add(userName1);
        userInterface.add(textUsername1);
        userInterface.add(userName2);
        userInterface.add(textUsername2);
        
        frame.add(container);
        container.add(board);
        container.add(userInterface);
        
        
        
        
        makeMenuBar();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private void makeMenuBar()
    {
        //Finish coding later
        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);
        
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        menubar.add(fileMenu);
        
        JMenuItem saveFile = new JMenuItem("Save File");
        fileMenu.add(saveFile);
        
        JMenuItem quitGame = new JMenuItem("Quit");
        fileMenu.add(quitGame);
        quitGame.addActionListener(ev -> {quit(); });
        
    }
    
    private void quit()
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to make them smaller where it can be placed on the Right side panel in the centre at the top. But not sure how to go about doing this.

```
userInterface.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,700));
```

First of all don't use the setPreferredSize() method. Each component is responsible for determining its own size.

```
//userInterface.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,700)); //delete
```

For your "board" panel, you will eventually be doing custom painting, so you should override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return the size. However, for some quick text code to test the layout you can keep the setPreferredSize().

Next, you can nest panels with different layout managers to achieve your desired layout.

You want to use a layout manager that will respect the preferred size of your components on the right.

The default layout manager of the JFrame is the BorderLayout. Take advantage of that.

So your code can be changed to something like:

```
//frame.add(container);
//container.add(board);
//container.add(userInterface);

frame.add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);

JPanel wrapper = new JPanel(); // uses FlowLayout by default and respects component size
wrapper.add(userInterface);
frame.add(wrapper, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
```

The "container" panel is not needed.